# Flutter WillPopScope doesn't catch android back button press

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

In my App I'm trying to adjust navigation: I want to do `Navigator.pop()` on android system back button press, but WillPopScope do doesn't catch this press event. At the same time it cathes back arrow button press as expected. How can I solve my problem?

[image]

[image]